# How to retrieve the max id value and store in a int variable?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have some data in my database, and there is an id column which increments automatically whenever a data is stored.

For some purpose I want to retrieve the last row added or the row with max id (which is also the last row). I am writing the below query as:

```
List<Student> student = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("SELECT * FROM Student ORDER BY id DESC")
```

I don't know whether it is right way to do, but while executing I am getting error like unexpected token: *.

Looking for your valuable suggestion and thanks in advance.

```
public void storeData(Student student)
{
   List<Student> std = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM Student ORDER BY id DESC limit 1").list(); //getting error while executing this statement(unexpected token limit)

   System.out.println(std.get(0).getNumber()); //getting error while executing it
}
```

I am sending the student data through student object in storeData class. I want that after storing data I can access the value of data stored, like I want to store the number value in a variable for further process. But while executing the above I am getting error.

Comment: Are you using Hibernate?

Comment: yes I am using Hibernate @kayaman

Comment: Then why are you writing SQL and not HQL?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, and i want to store the max(id) in a int variable. Is it possible to do the same with below syntax:


List<Student> student = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select max(id) from Student").list();

System.out.println(student.get(0).getId());

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply the "highest" ID?

```
select max(id) from student
```

Using the session factory:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select max(id) from student");
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, and i want to store the max(id) is a int variable. Is it possible to do the same with below syntax:
List<Student> student = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select max(id) from Student").list();

System.out.println(student.get(0).getId());

Answer (score 1):

Set Max Result option **.setMaxResults(1)**

There are two ways

1) with List as output using **.setMaxResults(1).list()**

So Your statement will become and you need to iterate it

```
List <Student> student = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM Student ORDER BY id DESC").setMaxResults(1).list();
```

2) As you only need last result then you can also go for **.setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult()**

```
   uniqueResult() : Convenience method to return a single instance that matches the query, or null if the query returns no results.
```

So Your statement will become

```
Student student = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM Student ORDER BY id DESC").setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();
```

Using any method you can save your id(max) in int variable

**[Note]: Remove Limit 1 from query**

Hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks! But can i store the value of id inside an int variable

Comment: Do you want id only? 
or you can get id from student object

Comment: Actually there is a column in table named "number" (of int data type), i want to retrieve that value and store it in another variable. Or the last number value stored in the database. I tried with lots of query but not able to convert it into integer.

Comment: please share your conversion code. are you getting any error?

Comment: Pallavi@ Please see above I updated my code and while executing the query mentioned by you, i am getting the error (unexpected token limit).

Comment: @AmitKumar Please confirm which frameworks you are using. May be the syntax are different

Comment: I am using Spring along with Hibernate

Comment: @AmitKumar Please See above I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Student ORDER BY id DESC limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `SELECT *` from your query, HQL [doesn't need it](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-from):

```
List<Student> student = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM Student ORDER BY id DESC");
```